# How to add a property to Azure table storage row with Azure Powershell module

Tags: powershell, azure-table-storage, azure-powershell

I need to add a new property to Azure table storage entities while updating records via [Azure PowerShell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell). I am hoping to achieve this through an update instead of deleting / adding a new entity.

The script I currently have follows Microsoft's [updating entities example](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell#updating-entities) closely and works great for updating existing properties. Below is a modified version of their example where I attempt to add a new "nickname" property.

```
$user = Get-AzTableRow -table $cloudTable -customFilter $filter

# Change the entity.
$user.username = "Jessie2"

# Attempting to add a new property 
$user.nickname= "Jess"

# To commit the change, pipe the updated record into the update cmdlet.
$user | Update-AzTableRow -table $cloudTable
```

As you might expect PowerShell throws an error because the row does not have an existing nickname property:
`Exception setting "nickname": "The property 'nickname' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and
can be set.`

Is deleting / creating a new entity the only way to add a new property?

Comment: He says in his blog post that he converts the row entries into PSCustomObjects, so it makes sense to treat it like such and use `Add-Member` to add a new property. Try changing `$user.nickname= "Jess"` to `Add-Member -InputObject $user -NotePropertyName 'nickname' -NotePropertyValue 'Jess'` or the shorter `$user|add-member 'nickname' 'Jess'`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Could you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He says in his blog post that he converts the row entries into PSCustomObjects, so it makes sense to treat it like such and use `Add-Member` to add a new property. Try changing

```
$user.nickname= "Jess"
```

to

```
Add-Member -InputObject $user -NotePropertyName 'nickname' -NotePropertyValue 'Jess'
```

or the shorter

```
$user|add-member 'nickname' 'Jess'
```